# loop to make every combination of several lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a somewhat complicated, or maybe not complicated, but long question that I'm going to try to distill down to just the basic parts and then maybe I can figure it out from there.

So what I'm trying to do is fill up a baseball roster. I have a list of players, which is then broken into several other lists, based on position. From this point, I want to fill the roster with every possible combination of players. I've written a basic script that accomplishes this, but as I have a large list, simply iterating through every combination is less than ideal. I used a subset of players just to test it, and it still took about an hour and a half.

Some players are eligible to be put in the roster at multiple positions, and as such, some names will be in two or more of the lists that I'm pulling names from. My first time-saving attempt it to check every iteration for whether it will contain a duplicate, and if so, skip that player.

```
import os, csv, time

player_pool_csv = open('Available Player Pool.csv', 'r') player_pool = csv.reader(player_pool_csv) player_pool = list(player_pool)

roster = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
# roster with characters is my solution to the TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' 
# when I check len(roster) against len(set(roster)) in the first loop

catcher_pool = []
first_pool = []
second_pool = []
third_pool = []
short_pool = []
of_pool = []

for player in player_pool:
    if 'C' in player[2]:
        catcher_pool.append(player)
    if '1B' in player[2]:
        first_pool.append(player)
    if '2B' in player[2]:
        second_pool.append(player)
    if '3B' in player[2]:
        third_pool.append(player)
    if 'SS' in player[2]:
        short_pool.append(player)
    if 'OF' in player[2]:
        of_pool.append(player)

start = time.time()

for catcher in catcher_pool:
roster[0] = catcher[0]
if len(roster) != len(set(roster)):
    continue
for first_baseman in first_pool:
    roster[1] = first_baseman[0]
    if len(roster) != len(set(roster)):
        continue
    for second_baseman in second_pool:
        roster[2]= second_baseman[0]
        if len(roster) != len(set(roster)):
            continue
        for third_baseman in third_pool:
            roster[3] = third_baseman[0]
            if len(roster) != len(set(roster)):
                continue
            for shortstop in short_pool:
                roster[4] = shortstop[0]
                if len(roster) != len(set(roster)):
                    continue
                for outfielder1 in of_pool:
                    roster[5] = outfielder1[0]
                    if len(roster) != len(set(roster)):
                        continue
                    for outfielder2 in of_pool:
                        roster[6] = outfielder2[0]
                        if len(roster) != len(set(roster)):
                            continue
                        for outfielder3 in of_pool:
                            roster[7] = outfielder3[0]
                            if len(roster) != len(set(roster)):
                                continue
                            print(roster)

end = time.time()
elapsed = end - start
print(elapsed)
```

When I run this code, it seems to stop itself during the "for outfielder2" loop at some point. I can't seem to put my finger on exactly why it stops when it does, and how to fix it.

I realize you may need more information than this, like the contents of the pools it's pulling players from, but I don't want to overload the question at first if it turns out not to be necessary. I'll put that stuff in if needed.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong, and how to make this more efficient? Thanks.

EDIT

Okay I pared my player_pool down to

```
['Ender Inciarte', '0.283', 'OF', '3900']
['A.J. Pollock', '0.304', 'OF', '4900']
['Jamie Romak', '0.349', 'OF', '2000']
['Adam Jones', '0.258', 'OF', '3700']
['Paul Goldschmidt', '0.343', '1B', '5600']
['Chris Davis', '0.306', '1B', '4300']
['Aaron Hill', '0.245', '2B/3B', '2400']
['Jimmy Paredes', '0.276', '1B/2B', '3000']
['Jake Lamb', '0.283', '3B', '3700']
['Manny Machado', '0.315', '3B', '4400']
['Welington Castillo', '0.31', 'C', '3800']
['Caleb Joseph', '0.266', 'C', '3200']
['Xander Bogaerts', '0.318', '3B/SS', '4300']
['Eugenio Suarez', '0.294', 'SS', '3000']
```

When I run the code with all of the `if len(roster) != len(set(roster))` commented out, it correctly returns every combination (takes 48.3 seconds per the timer I wrote into it). But if I put the `if len(roster) != len(set(roster))` back in, this is the output:

```
['Welington Castillo', 'Paul Goldschmidt', 'Aaron Hill', 'Jake Lamb', 'Xander Bogaerts', 'Ender Inciarte', 'A.J. Pollock', 'Jamie Romak']
['Welington Castillo', 'Paul Goldschmidt', 'Aaron Hill', 'Jake Lamb', 'Xander Bogaerts', 'Ender Inciarte', 'A.J. Pollock', 'Adam Jones']
['Welington Castillo', 'Paul Goldschmidt', 'Aaron Hill', 'Jake Lamb', 'Xander Bogaerts', 'Ender Inciarte', 'Jamie Romak', 'A.J. Pollock']
['Welington Castillo', 'Paul Goldschmidt', 'Aaron Hill', 'Jake Lamb', 'Xander Bogaerts', 'Ender Inciarte', 'Jamie Romak', 'Adam Jones']
0.03500199317932129
```

Comment: Start with itertools but quadratic is quadratic

Comment: This could be pretty simple, but can you include some example input and output?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham new to this - are you saying that no matter what, it's going to take a long time to cycle through all the combinations?

Comment: There's a lot of duplication. Anywhere you've copied and pasted, replace it with a function and parameter.

Comment: @Cyphase give me a second, will try to write up an easy-to-read example.

Comment: @jbf, yes, depending on the size of your input, for example 100 choose 3 would give you `161700` possible combinations so you can see how quickly  your data can grow, what is your input size?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yeah, that's why I'm trying to do a few things to cut down on the number of combinations, like heading off a loop when I know all of its results will be impractical.

Comment: I think adding some input and what you expect as output would help, there are no doubt some ways to improve the code but without knowing exactly what you want it is hard to suggest anything specifically

Comment: can you add the correct output for your test input?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham sorry, I re-edited after I changed my test code. I had the `print` command before the `len(roster)` at first.

Comment: @jbf, what is the logic behind  `if len(roster) != len(set(roster)):`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham that was my solution to checking for duplicates in the roster. E.g., in my example player_pool, Aaron Hill is eligible at 2B and 3B. If the third_base loop sees Aaron Hill while he's still in the 2B slot, there's no need to run all the possible sub-loops with him at 2B and 3B, so I want skip all of that unnecessary computing/wasted time.

Comment: did you try to save to a file instead of printing? using `out_file=open('out.txt','w')` and `print(rooster,file=out_file)` created [this](http://jpst.it/AZGa) big file instantaneously.

Comment: @orestisf, how would writing to a file be any faster? That makes no sense at  all.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham 
`python3 -c "for i in range(10000): print(i)"  0.06s user 0.01s system 49% cpu 0.135 total`

`python3 -c "for i in range(1000): print(i)" > out.log  0.02s user 0.00s system 97% cpu 0.021 total`

Comment: @orestisf, it is not going to change the complexity or  handle dupes which is what the OP is trying to do, also using product is not going to give the correct output either, there are six lists and eight positions to fill

Comment: Is this going to be any help? https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations
https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Comment: @PadraicCunningham You can use the last list 3 times and the result is the same as the original code.  OP doesn't mention complexity but speed.

Comment: @orestisf, use the last list three times so you can get even more duplicates?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Not more, same amount of dupes with op's original code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can optimize a lot by filtering the pools of the inner loops by the players you've already chosen in the outer loops. This is especially easy with sets.
You can also use `combinations` from itertools for your outerfield players to avoid another three loops.
The result looks like this:

```
import itertools as it
import time

player_pool = [['Ender Inciarte', '0.283', 'OF', '3900'],
               ['A.J. Pollock', '0.304', 'OF', '4900'],
               ['Jamie Romak', '0.349', 'OF', '2000'],
               ['Adam Jones', '0.258', 'OF', '3700'],
               ['Paul Goldschmidt', '0.343', '1B', '5600'],
               ['Chris Davis', '0.306', '1B', '4300'],
               ['Aaron Hill', '0.245', '2B/3B', '2400'],
               ['Jimmy Paredes', '0.276', '1B/2B', '3000'],
               ['Jake Lamb', '0.283', '3B', '3700'],
               ['Manny Machado', '0.315', '3B', '4400'],
               ['Welington Castillo', '0.31', 'C', '3800'],
               ['Caleb Joseph', '0.266', 'C', '3200'],
               ['Xander Bogaerts', '0.318', '3B/SS', '4300'],
               ['Eugenio Suarez', '0.294', 'SS', '3000']]

# create a player hash for later use, I hope player names are unique
player_hash = {p[0]: p for p in player_pool}

# use sets for the pools so that we can use set difference later on
catcher_pool = set()
first_pool = set()
second_pool = set()
third_pool = set()
short_pool = set()
of_pool = set()

# fill the pools only with player names
for player, stats in player_hash.items():
    if 'C' in stats[2]:
        catcher_pool.add(player)
    if '1B' in stats[2]:
        first_pool.add(player)
    if '2B' in stats[2]:
        second_pool.add(player)
    if '3B' in stats[2]:
        third_pool.add(player)
    if 'SS' in stats[2]:
        short_pool.add(player)
    if 'OF' in stats[2]:
        of_pool.add(player)

start = time.time()
playing = set()
all_rosters = []
roster = [None]*8

# create a little generator that only yields players from a pool
# which are currently not playing
def filtered(pool):
    for player in pool-playing:
        playing.add(player)
        yield player
        playing.remove(player)

with open('rosters.txt', 'w') as f:
    for catcher in filtered(catcher_pool):
        roster[0] = catcher
        for first_baseman in filtered(first_pool):
            roster[1] = first_baseman
            for second_baseman in filtered(second_pool):
                roster[2] = second_baseman
                for third_baseman in filtered(third_pool):
                    roster[3] = third_baseman
                    for shortstop in filtered(short_pool):
                        roster[4] = shortstop
                        for outfielders in it.combinations(of_pool-playing, 3):
                            roster[5:8] = outfielders
                            # append result to a list instead of printing
                            # this is a lot faster
                            all_rosters.append(roster[:])
                            # if our list is bigger than 1e6, write it to file
                            if len(all_rosters) > 10**6:
                                f.writelines(repr(roster)+'\n'
                                             for roster
                                             in all_rosters)
                                all_rosters = []
    # don't forget to write the last batch which did not reach 1e6
    f.writelines(repr(roster)+'\n' for roster in all_rosters)

end = time.time()
elapsed = end - start

# make sure no roster contains double names
assert all(len(set(roster)) == len(roster) == 8 for roster in all_rosters)

# make sure all rosters are unique
assert len(all_rosters) == len(set(tuple(roster) for roster in all_rosters))

print(len(all_rosters))
print(elapsed)
```

Prints:

```
[a lot of rosters]
232
0.00205016136169
```

But the results are **not** ordered. I gues that isn't a problem. If you want to sort them, just sort `all_rosters` after they were generated.

Comment: I mostly understand what you're doing here (not totally but I'm working on it), but when I run the code with a player_pool of 50 players, I get a MemoryError. Is this just a function of me running it on a not-super-fast laptop? When I test `len(all_rosters)` after the MemoryError, it's at 23242653.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid that would happen. This simply means that the memory allocated to Python is not large enough to hold all combinations. Depending on what you want to do with the rosters it might be wise to turn the whole thing into a generator and process them one by one. It would also be possible to print them in batches to a file for later use.

Comment: I thought about the concept of printing them to files in batches, but as I've never done this before, I wasn't sure how to implement it in actual practice, as the player_pool will be different sizes at different times. I think that's something I can probably figure out though. This is a good start, thanks.

Comment: It's just a few lines away, I'll edit it accordingly. Note however that I have no idea how meany combinations there really are... It would be possible to determine an upper-bound by multiplying the pool lengths and use this to create a rough progress bar. I could do that as well if you like.

Comment: I tried to put a progress bar on it for a while, but I got bogged down in all the nested loops and decided that wasn't a priority so I gave up on it for a while. First priorities were to get this running smoothly and then figure out a way to incorporate the `multiprocessing` module since my CPU isn't running at 100% in my tests. If it helps, player pool will never be > 270, but may be smaller sometimes. Pool lengths will vary though.

Comment: First I update the batch print to file. I have an Idea on how to get a better progress bar. However when using multithreading, usually progress bars slow you down a bit because they need synchronization. Maybe I'll try to parallelize it tomorrow ;)

Comment: 270?! You did notice the huge combination space? Lets be veeery optimistic and say with 270 players you can reduce your pools to equal sizes of 25 (this doesn't even add up to 270) and lets get rid of the combinations of OF's. You'll get 25\**6=244140625 combinations. Lets suppose each roster takes up 130 chars per line which is equal to 130bytes. Now your file will be (25\**6*130)/(1024\**3) = ~29Gb big. Lets say you use compression and only take one byte per player so 8 bytes per line. Your file will still be (25\**6*8)/(1024\**3) = ~2Gb big. And I bet the real number is a LOT worse...

Comment: Yeah I know it's a lot, this is really just a project for me to learn a little Python with, it's nothing thats imperative. But I do plan on doing a lot of filtering on the player pool beforehand to reduce its size. I was just saying 270 is an absolute maximum. Right now I'm just working with the 50 rows and trying to reduce that time as much as possible, as a test case. Thanks for your help!